# Why sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression with n_jobs = 2 performs so poorly?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, multiprocessing, google-compute-engine

I am building a model for MNIST database with logistic rergession using scikit-learn package. I noticed that with default parameters it performs very poorly, and after finding [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/logistic-regression-using-python-sklearn-numpy-mnist-handwriting-recognition-matplotlib-a6b31e2b166a) I changed `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression` solver to `'lbfgs'`. Fortunately it worked fine and the training of the model took just under 2 minutes using all 60000 elements from the training set.

I am working on Google Compute Engine, so I wanted to use multiple cores and try to train the model even faster. I set up an instance with 2 cores and put `n_jobs = 2` in `LogisticRegression`. However, the algorithm performed worse than with `n_jobs = 1`. Here is the snippet:

Import data and transform it to `np.ndarray` objects:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mnist import MNIST
mndata = MNIST('./data')

images_train, labels_train = mndata.load_training()
images_test, labels_test = mndata.load_testing()

labels_train = labels_train.tolist()
labels_test = labels_test.tolist()

X_train = np.array(images_train)
y_train = np.array(labels_train)
X_test = np.array(images_test)
y_test = np.array(labels_test)
```

Main function:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
import time

def log_test(train_size, c, cores):
    X_train = X_train_all[:train_size]
    y_train = y_train_all[:train_size]

    start_time = time.time()

    logreg = LogisticRegression(C = c, solver = 'lbfgs', n_jobs = cores).fit(X_train, y_train)
    print("Training set score: {:.3f}".format(logreg.score(X_train, y_train)))
    print("Test set score: {:.3f}".format(logreg.score(X_test_all, y_test_all)))

    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    print(elapsed_time)
```

Performance for `n_jobs = 1` vs `n_jobs = 2`:

- `log_test(2000, 100, 1)`  - 2s
- `log_test(2000, 100, 2)`  - 9s
- `log_test(5000, 100, 1)`  - 8s
- `log_test(5000, 100, 2)`  - 27s
- `log_test(7000, 100, 1)`  - 13s
- `log_test(7000, 100, 2)`  - 55s
- `log_test(15000, 100, 1)` - 27s
- `log_test(15000, 100, 2)` - 115s

> **Question.** How to use multiple cores to boost up the performance of the algorithm?

Comment: Parallelization usually introduces overhead (especially process-based) and your problem even be too small to get those speedups (not that many samples; convex-problem; small number of classes i suppose). If you are already using lbfgs, you might try ```multi_class='multinomial'```, which might speed up things, but won't not use any parallelization at all (useless to use more than 1 core).

Comment: @sascha Great! In fact `multi_class='multinomial'` cuts down training time from 110s to 36s and gets higher scores. As for the problem beeing too small: notice that the bigger the sample the bigger difference between 1CPU and 2CPUs. So I doubt that the bigger sample would make a difference.